# ui-router views not loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to find the best routing solution for my application, but my lack of experience with `ui-router` and its best practices is not helping.

My app will have a display of :
- **navbar-div** (`state1`) => always shown
- **content-div** with 3 tabs (each tab will be a state, so : `state2`/`state3`/`state4`) => `state2` is shown on page loading, then we can swith to `state3` or `state4` by clicking on corresponding tab.

All of these states will be children (?) of a `stateAlpha`. `alphaLayoutView` is displayed from my `ui-view` in `index.html`

```
$stateProvider.state('stateAlpha', {
        url: '/*path', //will be shown on any url
        views: {
            'alphaLayoutView@' : {
                templateUrl: '/app/screens/alphaLayout.html',
                controller: 'alphaLayout.controller',
                controllerAs: 'alphaLayoutVM'
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I plug the `state1/2/3/4` to my parent state (`stateAlpha`) template with a simple `ui-view` for each state ? 
Can I have my children states without URLs ? Will it be problematic to navigate between my states tabs ?

```
$stateProvider.state('state1', {
        views: {
            'state1View' : {
                templateUrl: '/app/screens/state1.html',
                controller: 'state1.controller',
                controllerAs: 'state1VM'
            }
        }
    });
...
```

I've tried different things, but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering you have states in following order:
stateAlpha(top state) -> state1(Contain 3 tabs) = >state2, state3, state4 (2,3 and 4 are siblings)

```
$stateProvider.state('stateAlpha', {
    url: '/stateAlpha',
    views: {
        '' : {
            templateUrl: '/app/screens/alphaLayout.html',
            controller: 'alphaLayout.controller',
            controllerAs: 'alphaLayoutVM'
        }
    }
})
.state('state1', {
    url: '^/state1url,
    views: {
        'alphaLayoutView@' : {
            templateUrl: '/app/screens/state1.html',
            controller: 'state1.controller',
            controllerAs: 'state1Ctrl'
        }
    }
})
.state('state2', {
    url: '^/state2url,
    views: {
        'state1LayoutView@' : {
            templateUrl: '/app/screens/state2.html',
            controller: 'state2.controller',
            controllerAs: 'state2Ctrl'
        }
    }
})
.state('state3', {
    url: '^/state3url,
    views: {
        'state1LayoutView@' : {
            templateUrl: '/app/screens/state3.html',
            controller: 'state3.controller',
            controllerAs: 'state3Ctrl'
        }
    }
})
.state('state4', {
    url: '^/state4url,
    views: {
        'state1LayoutView@' : {
            templateUrl: '/app/screens/state4.html',
            controller: 'state4.controller',
            controllerAs: 'state4Ctrl'
        }
    }
});
```

- Url for State1 = >   /state1url,
- Url for State2 = >   /state2url,
- Url for State3 = >   /state3url,
- Url for State4 = >   /state4url

If you remove '^' from the front of url's then it becomes:

- Url for State1 = >   /stateAlpha/state1url,
- Url for State2 = >   /stateAlpha/state1url/state2url,
- Url for State3 = >   /stateAlpha/state1url/state3url,
- Url for State4 = >   /stateAlpha/state1url/state4url,

view for stateAlpha must contain:

```
<div data-ui-view="alphaLayoutView"></div>
```

view for state1 must contain:

```
<div data-ui-view="state1LayoutView"></div>
```

Here add Content tabs and then div written above

Can I have my children states without URLs ? Will it be problematic to navigate between my states tabs ?

yes, you may have as much as children you want without URL. There is no issue even they don't have URL. UI-routing works on state.